# HTML float to right results in two lines. How do I adjust margin/padding

Tags: html, css

So I am converting an HTML page to PDF and I have a footer at the bottom of the pages. However, I cannot seem to get `float:right` to pad a little further to the left so that it doesn't result in two lines. Here's what I mean. This is my `p` tag:

```
<p style="text-align:left; color: #676B6D">
    <%= @report.project.company.full_name %> | Project Code: <%= @report.project.project_code %>
    <span style="float:right;">
        Confidential | Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
    </span>
</p>
```

And here's the CSS of `p` (nothing crazy):

```
    p {
        color: #545658;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-weight: 500;
    }
```

However, as you can see in the screenshot below, the "Page X of X" is spanning across two lines:

[image]

How do I adjust the span style so that I can get "page X of X" on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your span is floating over, but the container is too small for the text content. Adjust the width of the span should do it.

CSS

```
span {
  width: 200px;
}
```

OR inline HTML

```
   <p style="text-align:left; color: #676B6D">
     <%= @report.project.company.full_name %> | Project Code: <%= @report.project.project_code %>
     <span style="float:right;" width="200px">
       Confidential | Page <span class="page">5</span> of <span class="topage">5</span>
     </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding `width="200px"` but it's still going to the new line.

Comment: I placed that `width` inside of the `style` attribute and this fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!